# Connect to SQL Server on Ubuntu via Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu

I have a fresh SQL Server 2019 Developer installation on a Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS machine on IONOS.

Service is running

```
root@localhost:~# systemctl status mssql-server --no-pager
● mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-04-20 09:21:09 CEST; 15min ago
     Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
 Main PID: 819 (sqlservr)
    Tasks: 168
   CGroup: /system.slice/mssql-server.service
           ├─ 819 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
           └─1793 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr

Apr 20 09:36:21 localhost sqlservr[819]: [207B blob data]
Apr 20 09:36:21 localhost sqlservr[819]: [207B blob data]
Apr 20 09:36:21 localhost sqlservr[819]: [207B blob data]
Apr 20 09:36:21 localhost sqlservr[819]: [40B blob data]
Apr 20 09:36:21 localhost sqlservr[819]: [40B blob data]
Apr 20 09:36:21 localhost sqlservr[819]: [40B blob data]
Apr 20 09:36:21 localhost sqlservr[819]: [40B blob data]
Apr 20 09:36:21 localhost sqlservr[819]: [40B blob data]
Apr 20 09:36:21 localhost sqlservr[819]: [40B blob data]
Apr 20 09:36:21 localhost sqlservr[819]: [40B blob data]
```

Listening

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1431          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1793/sqlservr
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1433            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1793/sqlservr
tcp6       0      0 :::1434                 :::*                    LISTEN      1793/sqlservr
tcp6       0      0 :::1433                 :::*                    LISTEN      1793/sqlservr
```

I opened the firewall for ports 1433 and 1434 (TCP)

I am able to connect locally using the `sa` account.

But I am not able to connect from my laptop via Server Management Studio using the public IP of the ionos machine IP:217.x.x.x as servername.

Error Message is:

```
TITEL: Verbindung mit Server herstellen
------------------------------

Es kann keine Verbindung mit '217.x.x.x' hergestellt werden.

------------------------------
ZUSÄTZLICHE INFORMATIONEN:

Netzwerkbezogener oder instanzspezifischer Fehler beim Herstellen einer Verbindung mit SQL Server. Der Server wurde nicht gefunden, oder auf ihn kann nicht zugegriffen werden. Überprüfen Sie, ob der Instanzname richtig ist und ob SQL Server Remoteverbindungen zulässt. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Der Wartevorgang wurde abgebrochen.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Fehler: 258)

Hilfe erhalten Sie durch Klicken auf: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=258&LinkId=20476

------------------------------

Der Wartevorgang wurde abgebrochen

------------------------------
SCHALTFLÄCHEN:

OK
------------------------------
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Your host provider probably has other firewall rules that weren't disabled. Typically no host provider allows anything other than 80 and 443. If by `I am able to connect locally ` you mean you can SSH to the box and connect from the command line, there are two possibilities. 1) SQL Server isn't configured to allow remote connections and/or 2) the host provider blocks the ports.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you repsonse.
na, the provider isnt the problem. I have several other software installed using differrent ports (22, 22, 22, 22, 80, 443, 443, 443, 443, 443, 8008, 8043, 8181, 8443, 8443, 8448, 9000, 50080, 50080, 50080, 50080, 50080 ) all accessible from my network) 

Any ideas where to look for option 1?

Comment: Exposing an unprotected database to the public internet is a *very* bad idea. Hackers (and security researchers) use server farms on AWS or Azure to scan for known open ports and systems to audit or... attack. Worse, any connections to the server will be unencrypted. *At the very least* you'd need to use SSL to encrypt the connection. A VPN would be needed to protect access to the server

Comment: My response is `don't put a server on a public IP`

Comment: Thank you for your advice. No worries, the server is only accessible via our private network :-)

Comment: sp_configure shows
remote access                                 0           1            1           1
remote admin connections                      0           1            1           1

Comment: You probably need to configure `ufw` to allow incoming connections on tcp/1433. tcp/1434 is incorrect, by the way - the SQL Browser Service listens on udp/1434 to resolve instance names to tcp port numbers, but that only happens on Windows.

Comment: hmm maybe not the reason as: 
root@localhost:~# sudo ufw status
Status: inactive

Comment: how does your connection string looks like ? For linux I think it should be 217.x.x.x,1433 So put a `comma` between the ip and the port

Comment: Hello @GuidoG i try to use the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. The dialog asks me for an servertype (Database Engine), Servername (IP-Address), Authentication(Username SA and Password), i set additional connection parans to Databse MASTER and protocol TCP/IP

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Problem was the internal firewall which blocked the port outgoing.
Thanks to all trying to help.